# How to define an URL in the resource folder?

Tags: java, android, xml, emulation

I was learning how to connect to the internet by readiing a book, and in the first line of the example given was the following:

```
String myFeed = getString(R.string.my_feed);
```

I'm still learning how to connect to the internet but I could not understand what does R.string.my_feed means, and the author has not given any clue how my_feed is defined.

Now my question is, how to define my_feed? Should I create a folder named string and inside it write the website I want to have access to or what?

Comment: Just look at this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#String also as you learning android then also refers android developer guide..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an XML file reserved for defining custom strings, it is in `res/values/strings.xml`. If `strings.xml` doesn't exist, create it with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>    
  <string name="my_feed">http://myfeed.com</string>
</resources>
```

Then you can access it using

```
String myFeed = R.string.my_feed;  // (it becomes a static final property)
```

Answer (score 0):

R.string.my_feed represent the String defined in resource->values->strings.xml

```
String myFeed = getString(R.string.my_feed); gives the string value of this string resource
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings should go to the res/values/strings.xml file which could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="my_feed">http://google.com</string>
    <string name="app_name">My App</string>
    <string name="ctrl-shift-s">Ctrl-Shift-S</string>
</resources>
```

In code: `String myFeed = getString(R.string.my_feed);`

Answer (score 0):

You can just add textview on your layout where you want to put link like this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/link"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:text="http://www.yoursite.com"
     />
```

or

```
<TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/link"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:text="@string/click me"
         />
```

and in your strings.xml add:

```
<string name="click me"><a href="http://www.yoursite.com">Yoursite name</a></string>
```

Answer (score 0):

put your string strings.xml  and save it now you can get string

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>    
      <string name="my_feed">http://myfeed.com</string>
    </resources>
```